# Casting a Generic type to AnyRef in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a problem regarding type safety in scala. In fact, in Java I could cast a generic type to an Object. The annotation `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` did the job. However in scala I am struggling to find a way to do that. I have tried `Shapeless` API using `Typeable` class, didn't work either. Here's my code snippet :

```
class MyClass {
   val data: HashMap[String, AnyRef] = new HashMap[String, AnyRef]();

  def foo[T](key: String, value: Supplier[T]): T = synchronized {

       data.computeIfAbsent(key, (s: String) => { value.get() }) //(1)
       //(1) --> The compiler says : type mismatch; found : T required: AnyRef Note that T is unbounded, which means AnyRef is not a known parent.
       // Such types can participate in value classes, but instances cannot appear in singleton types or in reference comparisons
  }     
}
```

This is `data.computeIfAbsent()` signature : `data.computeIfAbsent(x: String, y: Function[ _ >: String, _ <: AnyRef]): AnyRef`. The function I am giving to `data.computeIfAbsent()` returns the generic type `T`. I am unable to cast `T` to `AnyRef`, that is why I am getting the error message above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest avoiding this specific problem by using `HashMap[String, Any]`, but to cast to `AnyRef` you just write `value.get().asInstanceOf[AnyRef]`. Of course,

```
data.computeIfAbsent(key, (s: String) => { value.get().asInstanceOf[AnyRef] })
```

will return `AnyRef`, not `T`. You can fix this with

```
data.computeIfAbsent(key, (s: String) => { value.get().asInstanceOf[AnyRef] }).asInstanceOf[T]
```

and it should be safe, but the compiler wouldn't help you spot the mistake if it weren't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still your proposed solution didn't work either. I am getting a new message error "type mismatch; found : AnyRef required: T" instead of "type mismatch; found : T required: AnyRef"

Comment: Are you talking about the first line or the second one? The second really shouldn't.

Comment: I am talking about the second one. I tried the first one though, did not work either.

Comment: You can see it compiles here: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/YpelI1H/0. So are you maybe getting the error in some other line (most likely when you access `data`)?

Comment: In 2.11 one can use [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for casting in Scala?

```
import java.util.HashMap
import java.util.function.Supplier

class MyClass {

  val data: HashMap[String, AnyRef] = new HashMap[String, AnyRef]()

  def foo[T <: AnyRef](key: String, value: Supplier[T]): T = synchronized {

    data.computeIfAbsent(key, (s: String) => value.get()).asInstanceOf[T] 
  }
}
```

Comment: No that's not what I asked for. Thread has beed updated for more clearance.

Comment: What is your version of Scala? In 2.12.4 my code compiles. Why can't you use it?

Comment: I was using 2.11. Problem fixed. Thank you.